# works in g++ ubuntu but shows segmentation fault in visual studio, code blocks and g++ in mac

Tags: c++

this is a code for a dictionary. 
each node has 26 pointers and so on.

this code works for around 270 word insertions in linux g++ compiler
but shows segmentation fault even on g++ in mac and fedora, and shows some exception handling error in visual studio 2010.
if more than 275 word are inserted automatically, it shows segmentation fault(ubuntu).

i am not worried about the efficiency of the prog. and that txt file used, contains a list of english words each in a single line.

i just need it to work. thanks in advance..

```
#define alphabets 26

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class dictionary
{
//// letter node ////
struct node
{
    char letter;
    char * meaning;
    bool completion;
    struct node * pointer[alphabets];
    }* root, * temp;



public:
char * word;    
int length;
int letterPos;
int pointerId;
bool searchFound;
bool inserted;



//// constructor ////
dictionary()
{
    root = new struct node;
    root -> letter = '0';
    root -> meaning = new char[9];
    strcpy(root -> meaning, "rootNode");
    root -> completion = 0; 
    }


//// called from localfunction ////
int insertWord(struct node *& currentNode)
{
    if(currentNode == NULL && letterPos < length)
    {
        //cout << "creating new node" << endl;
        //cout << "in insert function" << " " << word[letterPos] << endl;
        temp = new struct node;
        temp -> letter = word[letterPos];
        currentNode = temp;
        temp -> meaning = NULL;
        //cout << "node address: " << currentNode << endl;
        if(letterPos == length - 1)
        {
            temp -> completion = 1;
            inserted = 1;
            //cout << "inserted" << endl;
            return 0;
            }
        else    
            temp -> completion = 0;

        letterPos++;
        pointerId = word[letterPos] - 'a';
        insertWord(currentNode -> pointer[pointerId]);
        }
    else{

    /*if(letterPos == length - 1)
    {
        cout << "word inserted" << endl;
        currentNode -> completion = 1;
        return 0;
        }*/
    //else
    {
        letterPos++;
        pointerId = word[letterPos] - 'a';
        insertWord(currentNode -> pointer[pointerId]);
        }
    }



    if(letterPos == length)
    {
        //cout << "node letter: " << currentNode -> letter << endl;
        currentNode -> completion = 1;
        //cout << "inseted" << endl;
        inserted = 1;
        return 0;
        }

    /*if(currentNode -> letter == word[letterPos])
        if(letterPos == length - 1)
        {
            cout << "in if condition completion" << endl;
            currentNode -> completion = 1;
            }
    */

    //pointerId = word[letterPos] - 'a';

    }   

//// called from main ////      
int insertIntoDictionary(char * wordNew)
{
    length = strlen(wordNew);
    word = wordNew;
    letterPos = 0;
    inserted = 0;
    pointerId = word[letterPos] - 'a';
    //insertWord(root);
    //cout << "Root: " << root << endl;
    insertWord(root -> pointer[pointerId]);
    }


//// called from localfunction ////
int search(struct node * currentNode)
{
    //cout << "in search function" << " searching " << word[letterPos] << endl;
    if(currentNode == NULL)
    {
        //cout << "end of search" << endl;
        return 0;
        }
    /*if(currentNode == root)
    {
        cout << "search function in root " << endl;
        pointerId = word[letterPos] - 'a';
        search(currentNode -> pointer[pointerId]);
        return 0;
        }*/
    if(word[letterPos] == '\0' && !currentNode -> completion)
    {
        searchFound = 0;
        return 0;
        }
    if(currentNode -> letter == word[letterPos] && word[letterPos] != '\0')
    {
        //cout << "in if condition" << endl;
        if(letterPos == length - 1)
        {
            if(currentNode -> completion)
                searchFound = 1;
            return 0;
            }
        letterPos++;
        pointerId = word[letterPos] - 'a';
        //letterPos++;
        search(currentNode -> pointer[pointerId]);
        /*if(letterPos == length)
        {
            //cout << "word found" << endl;
            searchFound = 1;
            return 0;
            }*/
        }
    /*else
    {
        pointerId = word[letterPos] - 'a';
        //letterPos++;
        search(currentNode -> pointer[pointerId]);
        }
    */

    }


//// called from main ////  
int searchInDictionary(char * wordFind) 
{
    word = wordFind;
    length = strlen(wordFind);
    letterPos = 0;
    searchFound = 0;
    pointerId = word[letterPos] - 'a';
    search(root -> pointer[pointerId]);
    //if(searchFound)

        //cout << "Word found" << endl;
    }


int display1(struct node * currentNode)
{
    int i;
    if(currentNode != NULL)
    {
        //cout << "node letter1: " << currentNode -> letter << endl;
        for(i = 0; i < alphabets; i++)
            display1(currentNode -> pointer[i]);
        }
    }
/*int display()
{
    cout << "display function" << endl;
    //letterPos = 0;
    //pointerId = word[letterPos] - 'a';
    //cout << root -> 
    //display1(root -> pointer[pointerId]);
    cout << "root: " << root << endl;
    pointerId = word[letterPos] - 'a';
    cout << root -> pointer[0] << endl; //-> letter;
    display1(root);
    }*/
};




int autoInsert(dictionary &english)
{
int count = 0;
//dictionary english;
FILE * file = fopen("words2.txt", "r");
char * line;
char ch;
/*while(fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
{
    cout << "Inserting: " << line << endl;
    english.insertIntoDictionary(line);
    }*/
line = new char[25];
const char * ptr = &ch;
while( count < 274 && ( ch = fgetc(file) ) != EOF )
{
    if(ch != '\n')
        strcat(line, ptr);
    else
    {
        count++;
        cout << "Inserting: " << line << endl;
        english.insertIntoDictionary(line);
        delete [] line;
        line = new char[25];
        }
    }
return 0;
}


int main()
{
/*dictionary english;
char * word = "apple";
cout << "insert command" << endl;
english.insertIntoDictionary(word);

cout << "search command" << endl;
english.searchInDictionary(word);
*/
system("clear");
dictionary english;
int ch;
char w[100];
start:
cout << "1. insert word\n2. search\n3. auto insert\n4. exit " << endl;
cout << "Enter choice: ";
cin >> ch;
if(ch > 3)
    return 0;
if(ch != 3)
{
    cout << "word: ";
    cin >> w;
    }
switch(ch)
{
    case 1: english.searchInDictionary(w);
        if(english.searchFound)
        {
            cout << "word already exists" << endl;
            break;
            }
        english.insertIntoDictionary(w);
        if(english.inserted)
            cout << "word inserted" << endl;
        break;
    case 2: english.searchInDictionary(w);
        if(english.searchFound)
            cout << "Word found" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Word not found" << endl;
        break;
    case 3: autoInsert(english);
        break;
    default: return 0;
    }
goto start;
return 0;
}
```

---

here is the complete code:
http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/10XL

and the txt file link:
http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/10XN

Comment: Did you tried to use a debugger ?

Comment: You should recode this using standard template library classes. Use std::string for your strings, and std::set for your dictionary. Then watch your memory faults disappear.

Comment: What's the format of `words2.txt`?

Comment: first word in the first line then the next word in the second line and so on

Comment: i didn't use a debugger

Comment: maybe i accidentally deleted something when removing unwanted commented lines

Comment: posted the exact original code

Comment: @abilash, run your program with gdb : `gdb ./prog` (don't forget to compile with `-g` option) and show us the result.

Comment: @Michael it says =
gdb: unrecognized option '-g'

Comment: @Bathsheba i am not a very experienced programmer. so i dont know how to use std::set

Comment: @user2911808 - thanks for the input-file format. Found a missing bracket, that fixed the build-process. I'm a little concerned about the function `auto_insert` - you're not actually initializing the `line` variable. You're allocating memory to it, but just getting the memory in the state that it was before you asked for it. So, you should try `line = new char[25]; line[0] = 0;` Otherwise, if you get 25 bytes of memory and none of them are a NULL, `strcat` will keep searching until it finds one. When it does, it will try to copy the string there - whether you own the memory or not.

Comment: @abliash; learn to use std::set and acquire experience. A good C++ programmer must know the standard template library.

Comment: @abilash, I mean compile your program with `-g` option (option of g++) and just run `gdb ./prog`

Comment: @Michael sorry for not reading the statement properly.
did that got some txt regarding warranty about gdb then: 
Reading symbols from /home/abilash/Desktop/Progs/dictionary/dictionary_autoInsert...done.

Comment: @Bathsheba thanks for the advice. will get used to it.

Comment: @abilash, ok it seems that everything is OK with gdb, there is probably something wrong with the memory, now try `valgrind ./prog`

Comment: tried in fedora
got segmentation fault. have to go back to ubuntu and try valgrind

Comment: @Michael output of valgrind   http://justpaste.it/dfd1

Comment: @enhzflep tried tat. didnt fix it.

Comment: @Michael clear output of valgrind: http://justpaste.it/dfd5

Comment: another problem is that if the entire txt file which has around a thousand words is inserted, it shows segmentation fault.

Comment: @abilash, the issue is in `insertWord`, `currentNode` is not initialized. This confirms the answer of @krunal

Comment: @abilash, there is also an issue with `strcat` in `autoInsert` function.

Comment: finally found out that had problem in the retrieval from file in the autoInsert function. Fixed that. now i am trying to create a gui in visual studio, but shows unhandled exception, memory access violaton.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening may be because the pointer[alphabets] is not getting initialized when creating a new node.
Try this definition for struct node

```
//// letter node ////
struct node
{
    char letter;
    char * meaning;
    bool completion;
    struct node * pointer[alphabets];
    node()
    {
        for(int i =0; i<alphabets;i++)
        {
            pointer[i]=NULL;
        }
    }
}* root, * temp;
```

Comment: your valgrind's report confirms that answer.

Comment: got it to work on visual studio but had other problems.
will post the altered code.

Answer (score 0):

this is the altered code for the function autoInsert();

```
int autoInsert(dictionary &english)
{
int count = 0;
fstream file("123.txt",ios::in);
char * line = NULL;
char ch;
line = new char[25];
line[0] = '\0';
ch='\0';
char * ptr = &ch;
while( count < 1510 &&  file.getline(line,25,'\n'))
{
    {
        count++;
        cout << "Inserting: " << line << endl;
        english.insertIntoDictionary(line);
        }
    }
    file.close();
return 0;
}
```

this works perfectly on code blocks but shows unhandled exception, memory access violation.